# Pie-chart responsive with hardcoded data

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg width="100" height="100" class="pie-chart">
      <circle r="25" cx="50" cy="50" style="stroke-dasharray: 94.8, 158"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'pie-chart',
  data () {
    return {
      data: [10, 60, 30]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.pie-chart {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.pie-chart circle {
  fill: #ddd;
  stroke: #0074d9;
  stroke-width: 50;
}
</style>
```

[image: This is how it look at the moment]

I am trying to implement this pie-chart that changes according to the data setted, however once I set the values in data, where am I suppose to use data in the html in order for the chart to change accordingly? Or what am I suppose to do in order to achieve this?? thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest to you to make use of [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). It is a very handy library it simplifies a lot the creation of charts and also you wouldn't need to take care of the responsiveness, which personally I see as a pain to do in any svg circle.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Could you suggest me an example where this library is used?? Their documentations is so confusing, and the examples are incompletely explained.
Cheers